# Extracting namespace-prefix from an XML using XSLT

Tags: xslt, xml-namespaces

I have a SOAP XML. I need to take the XML into a variable and then I have to extract the namespace prefix from that variable using XSLT.

For example, if my XML is,

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:out="http://soap.sforce.com/2005/09/outbound" xmlns:urn="urn:sobject.enterprise.soap.sforce.com">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <a>
            <s>sakdjhkjh</s>
            <j>jhgkjhkjd</j>
        </a>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I have to take it into a variable called input(`<xsl:variable name="input"><xsl:copy-of select="."/></xsl:variable>`).

Now, from this variable ($input), I have to extract the namespace prefix 'soapenv'.

If my data is,

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:out="http://soap.sforce.com/2005/09/outbound" xmlns:urn="urn:sobject.enterprise.soap.sforce.com">
    <soap:Header/>
    <soap:Body>
        <a>
            <s>sakdjhkjh</s>
            <j>jhgkjhkjd</j>
        </a>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

then I have to get soap in my XSLT output.

Can someone help me out here.

Thank You,

Najma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well with XSLT 1.0 you should use `<xsl:variable name="input" select="."/>` instead of the one you have, as otherwise doing any path access is not possible (as your variable contains a result tree fragment in XSLT 1.0). As for the prefix, you could try `substring-before(name($input/descendant-or-self::*), ':')`.

Answer (score 0):

In these cases you can also use the rarely needed `namespace` axis. The value of a namespace node is the namespace URI and the name of the namespace node is the namespace prefix. For clarity, the namespace URI is defined as a variable that is then referenced.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">

        <!-- variable definitions -->
        <xsl:variable name="input" select="."/>
        <xsl:variable name="nsUri" select="'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'"/>

        <!-- getting the namespace prefix -->
        <xsl:value-of select="name($input/*/namespace::*[. = $nsUri])"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

(Although it is uncommon, a certain namespace URI can have several prefixes, the prefix can be redefined later in the document and elements can use different prefixes that are bound to same namespace. This example code searches the root element for a namespace definition and returns the first prefix of the given URI.)